# ONLY Publish app in Google Play Store

Tags: android-studio, google-play, app-store

I have a client who would like me to publish his app on Google Play Store. He has given me the .apk, description, icons, and banners.

I am going to buy a developer account ($25) for him but before that I would like to ask you guys that as I didn't actually develop this app. I am only going to publish his app. Is it safe? What key points I should check?

Also, would I still need to have Android Studio JUST to publish an app to Google Play Store? Or the URL below would give me the opportunity to publish my app using website?

https://play.google.com/apps/publish

Please help!

Thank you!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this doesn't seem to be a programming question - see http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/272165/are-developer-centric-questions-about-application-stores-on-topic

Answer (score 1):

Check the Google Play Store Developer Policy Center to see if it infringes any rules.

https://play.google.com/about/developer-content-policy

I would also consider asking to review the source code as well if your name or company is going to be associated with the product you publish.

Answer (score 0):

So basically uploading an app that copyrights most of someone's legit coding and possibly licensing? Not a good approach.

If you are aware about the terms and conditions, you would be liable for cost and damages because technically it will be under your name if you go forward and if your profiting this commercially, that case would be serious should it be brought forward on complaint.

EDITED

If you doing this on his behalf, he should sign up for Developer account or allow you to put his information in. So that's the safe point. If you are saying it is his app.

Comment: He is actually allowing me to publish his app as he is asking me to do so. It's not like I am copying his code and publish my own app. He has sent me all the necessaries like .apk file, icon files, banners, screenshots. That's the reason I would like to know what KEY things I should check before publishing the app. There are so many users out there who are actually providing these kind of services so I don't think there should be any harm if some points are covered.

Comment: @Obaid  That's fine. It is your client. As mentioned earlier, if it is under your name or company name, you or the company will be liable under Googles use of service on the developer console of that app. Whether you are freelance, contractor, developer in a company, LLC, it is responsible for anyone engaged in client projects, small or big to know their own parties rights.  Yes it is safe because if your client intends to make monetise the app too, you have to provide your personal information for the public of internet to know (e.g. Google Merchant Account).

Comment: @Obaid https://play.google.com/about/developer-content-policy/    and https://play.google.com/intl/ALL_us/about/play-terms.html     Please refer to the small prints if your client intends you to use it for money-making purposes.